# Jest exception match both type and message

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to write a test an exception where both the type and the message is important.

```js
function foo(){
    throw new CustomError("foobar");
}
```

Is there a better way to test this than calling the function twice?

```js
test("should throw a CustomError with the right message", () => {
    expect(() => foo()).toThrow(CustomError);
    expect(() => foo()).toThrow("foobar");
});
```

Comment: Looks like that is currently the only way to test that it is both an instance of `CustomError` *and* has the message `"foobar"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're asking for was requested and denied in [Jest GitHub issue #3659](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3659). However, it was added to the separate jest-extended project as [`toThrowWithMessage()`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#tothrowwithmessagetype-message). It's great!

Your example code would look like this:

```js
test("should throw a CustomError with the right message", () => {
    expect(() => foo()).toThrowWithMessage(CustomError, "foobar");
});
```

See [the documentation](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#tothrowwithmessagetype-message) for slightly more info. Note that there is a little configuration required in order to use their matchers beyond simply installing jest-extended. See [the setup section of their documentation](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#setup) for details.

If you prefer not to use jest-extended then you could always copy their matcher into your codebase, provided [the license](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended/blob/master/LICENSE) is acceptable to you. Otherwise I think the example you provided is a good way to check both error class and message.

Answer (score -1):

If you want this exact error, consider using following:

```
test("should throw a CustomError with the right message", () => {
    expect(() => foo()).toThrow(new CustomError("foobar");
});
```

as described [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror)

Comment: Linked documentation states that this only tests the `.message` property, not the type. The expectation passes if I change to `throw new Error("foobar")`.